# Adding a legend to points in the tmap package

Tags: r, legend, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to create a map with several points (about 20), where each point will be represented by a number, and where a legend will have these numbers and names of my points. 
Is it possible to do it with the tmap package (or any other R package)?

This is what I have:

```r
library(sf)                                                                        
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.0, GDAL 2.1.2, proj.4 4.9.2
library(tmap)                                                                      
data(Europe)                                                                       

df_obj <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), name=c("First", "Second"), x=c(0, 25), y=c(45, 50))
sf_obj = st_as_sf(df_obj, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)                        

tm_shape(st_as_sf(Europe)) +                                                       
  tm_polygons() +                                                                    
  tm_text("iso_a3", size="AREA", root=4) +                                           
  tm_shape(sf_obj) +                                                                 
  tm_symbols() +                                                                     
  tm_text("id", col="name") +                                                        
  tm_format_Europe() +                                                               
  tm_style_bw()
```

[image]

This is what I want (see the legend):

[image]

Comment: is base plot an option or you need it with ggplot2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two cents... Set `labels` and `text` in `tm_add_legend()` and set `legend.col.show = F` in `tm_text`:

```
tm_shape(st_as_sf(Europe)) +                                                       
  tm_polygons() +                                                                    
  tm_text("iso_a3", size="AREA", root=4) +                                           
  tm_shape(sf_obj) +                                                                 
  tm_symbols() +         
  tm_text("id", col="name",legend.col.show = F) + 
  tm_add_legend(title = 'name',type = 'text',labels = sf_obj$name, text = sf_obj$id) +
  tm_format_Europe() +                                                               
  tm_style_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to use this code to do a similar thing, but am ending up with absurdly small text (the 1, 2, 3 .. etc) next to correctly sized labels. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @cschwab98 add size argument. I.e., `tm_add_legend(title = 'name',type = 'text',labels = sf_obj$name, text = sf_obj$id, size = 4)`

Answer (score 2):

here is a base plot solution for you:

```
library(sf)                                                                        
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.0, GDAL 2.1.2, proj.4 4.9.2
library(magrittr)                                                                    
data(Europe)                                                                       

df_obj <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), name=c("First", "Second"), x=c(0, 25), y=c(45, 50))
sf_obj <- st_as_sf(df_obj, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)                        

euro <- st_as_sf(Europe) %>% 
  st_transform(4326) %>% 
  st_geometry

plot(euro, col='lightgrey', axes= T)
plot(sf_obj, add= T, pch= 19, cex=2.5, col="black",)
df_obj %$% 
  text(x,y,id,cex=1, col='white')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess but does it work if instead of

```
tm_text("id", col="name")
```

you use

```
tm_add_legend(type = "text", labels = "id")
```

I hope this works for you

source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/tmap.pdf